# cakephp 4 Testing Actions That Require Authentication

Tags: authentication, testing, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Testing actions that require authentication do not work as describe [cakephp manual](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication).

I found this solution, is it the correct one ?

```
use App\Model\Entity\User;
...
public function testLogout()
{
    $user=new User();
    $user->id=1;

    $this->session(['Auth' => $user]);

    $this->get ( '/Users/logout' );
    $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
}
```

Comment: If you're using the new authentication plugin, then you need to refer to **https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/testing.html**.

Comment: Thanks, ndm, yes I use the new authentication plugin, it works.
[This part of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication) is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is (thanks ndm):

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
...
protected function login($userId = 1)
{
    $users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
    $user = $users->get($userId);
    $this->session(['Auth' => $user]);
}

...

$this->login(1);

$this->enableRetainFlashMessages();
$this->get ( '/Users/logout' );
....
```